# Image processing framework using Android camera2 API and OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-camera2

I am new to camera2 api. I want to build an image processing framework on my Android phone.

**Step1:** use the Camera2 API to open a camera preview stream

**Step2:** feed the preview frame data to OpenCV for processing

**Step3:** display the processed result live on the screen

Currently, I have finished Step1 using `ImageReader` and C++ OpenCV code. However, I don't know how to do step3. 
How do I display the processed image on the screen? (I want to display the normal image, and overlay an icon if I detect predefined object)

Here are some key codes:

```
protected void createCameraPreview() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
      //  Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        Surface mImageSurface = mImageReader.getSurface();
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
      //  captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageSurface);


        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(mImageSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        //The camera is already closed
                        if (null == cameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }
                        cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                        updatePreview();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

protected void updatePreview() {
    if(null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
    }
    try {
        cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener  = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onImageAvailable: " + count++);
        Image img = null;
        img = reader.acquireNextImage();
        try {
            if (img == null) throw new NullPointerException("cannot be null");
            ByteBuffer buffer = img.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(data);
            int width = img.getWidth();
            int height = img.getHeight();

            // ****try to get captured img for display here (synchronized)

            // ****try to process image for detecting the object here (asynchronized)

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            Log.e(TAG, "in the finally! ------------");
            if (img != null)
                img.close();

        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Jun, Did you figure out how to make this work? Because I am also interested in this topic.

Comment: I am working on it. It is very close to success. Basically, I use renderscript to transform captured YUV_420_888 image to RGB bitmap. Then use Opencv (NDK) to process it. Will update soon.

Comment: Jun,

Sounds good. I'm hoping to find something that works in real time, reprocessing the live, moving image as the camera is used. But limiting the exposure of the camera (so that it is not constantly adjusting the exposure) and processing the live image has been the problem. I can process a live image using c++ in OpenCV, and I can control the camera with Camera2.CaptureRequest, but doing both has been a problem.

Comment: I'll add that I don't see how one can control or limit what the camera captures in OpenCV, since OpenCV doesn't work directly with android.hardware.camera2. Using ...camera2 exposes CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME and CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY before the preview sessions starts. 

I believe those properties need to be controlled BEFORE OpenCV get's the image for processing.

Comment: You can see where someone tried this here, but also failed to make it work: http://pastebin.com/3XgvKGQN

Comment: You should adjust exposure time using Camera2 API, then feed the captured image to OpenCV function. The problem is that not all Android devices support adjustment of exposure time, ISO and etc. You can see my two new questions today, if your device support the adjustment, you can use TEMPLATE_MANUAL to set the exposure time.